# click opens all divs instead of one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm really new to jQuery, i'm in the middle of a small crisis.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".help_box").click(function(){
        $(".help_box_answer").toggle(400);
    });
});
```

Here's the HTML itself

```
<div class="help_box">
    <div class="help_box_title">title box</div>
        <div class="help_box_answer">
            <p>Hidden message</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

the `class="help_box_answer"` is set to `display:none`

When I click on the div, this happens

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `this` to refer to only the element you're clicking on instead of all the divs with the same class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".help_box").click(function(){
        $(this).find(".help_box_answer").toggle(400);
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7na4y5xz/)**

Comment: Or `$(".help_box_answer", this).toggle(400);`

Comment: @Rayon - yes, they're essentially equivalent. However I think new users tend to get confused by the context selector syntax whereas using `.find()` is a little more readable.